# How to rename devices for graphical output such as VGA0

Tags: devices, udev, xrandr

On my Laptop the names of my graphical outputs change depending on what chip is activated in the BIOS. This leads to problems in some scripts where outputs such as VGA-0 or LVDS-0 are specified.
So I want to rename the graphical outputs, similar to how you can specify persistent names for network devices with `udev`.

But I can't find anything that would explain how or if this is even possible at all.

In /sys I could find kernel names such as as:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DVI-D-1
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1
```

while `xrandr` reports the names as `DVI1` and `VGA1`.
So they have to be renamed somewhere(?)
When I call `udevadm info` on one of those devices I get a lot of information but not the names used by `xrandr` and other X tools.

So is it possible to create a `udev` rule to rename the outputs and if so how?
Are the names even set by `udev`?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to use `xrandr` in the first place? I mean parse it's output to get the names you need rather than hard coding them into your scripts. This sounds like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101) problem. What do your scripts do?

Comment: Maybe I should have elaborated some more (or less). The outputs are not actually specified inside a script but in a config file for my window manager (i3). There might be some other way, I'm actually pretty sure there is. But I still want to know if the outputs can be renamed or not.

Comment: Have you found a clean way to solve this yet?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the output is set by the graphics card driver. This is then passed through X to xrandr. I believe they base it on the kernel device name but there is no standard scheme that is used.

[thinkwiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2#Output_port_names) documents some of the variations.